# Backend is ok but frontend is acting abnormally after upgrading Magento to 2.3 and php to 7.1

Tags: php, magento2.3, magento-upgrade, php-7.1

I upgraded Magento to v2.3 from v2.2. I also upgraded my php from 7.0 to 7.1. So right now, the backend is working fine but my frontend keeps showing the following error

```
    2 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist
    Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist
#0 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#1 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#2 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#3 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Template/FilterProvider.php(58): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#4 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Template/FilterProvider.php(82): Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider->_getFilterInstance('Magento\\Widget\\...')
#5 /var/www/aslive/app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/Helper/Generator.php(121): Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider->getPageFilter()
#6 /var/www/aslive/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/MGS_Mmegamenu/templates/navigation.phtml(4): MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper\Generator->filter('      \r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t...')
#7 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/aslive...')
#8 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(MGS\Mmegamenu\Block\Mmegamenu), '/var/www/aslive...', Array)
#9 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/aslive...')
#10 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#11 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('megamenu')
#13 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('megamenu')
#14 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(508): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('megamenu', true)
#15 /var/www/aslive/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml(14): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('megamenu')
#16 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/aslive...')
#17 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header), '/var/www/aslive...', Array)
#18 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/aslive...')
#19 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('header')
#22 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header')
#23 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header', false)
#24 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header.containe...', false)
#25 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#26 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.containe...', false)
#27 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#28 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#29 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#30 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#31 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#32 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#33 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#34 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#35 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#36 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#37 /var/www/aslive/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#38 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#39 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#40 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#41 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#42 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php(39): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#43 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#44 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#45 /var/www/aslive/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#46 {main}

Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables does not exist
#0 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(29): ReflectionParameter->getClass()
#1 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#2 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#3 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#4 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Template/FilterProvider.php(58): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Cloudinary\\Clou...')
#5 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Template/FilterProvider.php(82): Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider->_getFilterInstance('Magento\\Widget\\...')
#6 /var/www/aslive/app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/Helper/Generator.php(121): Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider->getPageFilter()
#7 /var/www/aslive/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/MGS_Mmegamenu/templates/navigation.phtml(4): MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper\Generator->filter('      \r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t...')
#8 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/aslive...')
#9 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(MGS\Mmegamenu\Block\Mmegamenu), '/var/www/aslive...', Array)
#10 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/aslive...')
#11 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('megamenu')
#14 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('megamenu')
#15 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(508): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('megamenu', true)
#16 /var/www/aslive/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml(14): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('megamenu')
#17 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/aslive...')
#18 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header), '/var/www/aslive...', Array)
#19 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/aslive...')
#20 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('header')
#23 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header')
#24 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header', false)
#25 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header.containe...', false)
#26 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#27 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.containe...', false)
#28 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#29 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#30 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#31 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#32 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#33 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#34 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#35 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#36 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#38 /var/www/aslive/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#39 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#40 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#41 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#42 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#43 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php(39): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#44 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#45 /var/www/aslive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#46 /var/www/aslive/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#47 {main}
```

Comment: Are you using any custom module?

Answer (score 1):

some code of `MGS_Mmegamenu` oR  `Cloudinary_Cloudinary` is not supported for 7.1.

I guess you need to update these two extensions.https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_magento2